# How to send logs to plugin owner for a plugin?

Tags: php, plugin-development, errors, privacy, logging

I am developing a plugin(that is already on WordPress) and wanted to know that how to do set up to get error logs from customers? Also, any idea on how to omit logs that should only be shown to customers and not included in final file sent to plugin owner(to maintain privacy and also allowing customer to debug at the same time in case the logs sent are not enough to debug)?

Comment: Have a look on this plugin Download "Error Log Monitor" https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/error-log-monitor/  from the plugin repository, you can easily refactor the plugin's code into your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

> wanted to know that how to do set up to get error logs from customers?

If you want to do this, your best option is to use a 3rd party service that logs errors (whether it be PHP/JS/Web server errors).

I'm not sure if you can choose what type of bugs you want to show customers, maybe log to a different error log file depending on what type of error you find?

The following services can do what you need:

PHP - https://airbrake.io/languages/php_bug_tracker

JS - https://sentry.io/for/javascript/